# 404 not found error for JavaScript files when accessing web page on localhost

Tags: windows-7, php, localhost, iis-7, fastcgi

The page loads up fine, but console shows a 404 not found error for JavaScript files. I have verified that the code contains the correct JavaScript file name. Any ideas?

The JavaScript file is loaded like this of course by HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Environment: Windows 7; FastCGI; PHP. 
The instructions for installation came from this site:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx
```

I made a basic html file that looks like this:

```
<html>

<head></head>
<body>

hello again.
<div id="11">
hello
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/analyst_scrape/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#11").click(fucntion(){

    alert("good bye");
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file gives me a blank page. However when i change the file ext to .php, I get the following error in console:

```
GET http://localhost/analyst_scrape/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) test.php:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are simply specifying the wrong path. You have not given *any* information about what you are actually doing so this is just speculation. You mention `cgi/php`so I assume you are serving a page that generates the html by running a `php` script in the `cgi/php` directory under your page's root.

If that is the case, if the root of your page is `foo`, then the page you are viewing is in `foo/cgi/php/` and your javascript file is probably in `foo` itself. Try specifying the correct path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.js"></script>
```

Or even the full URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foo.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I type in the url of the JS file, it gives a blank page in chrome.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza please explain how your page is set up. A 40-4 error means the file was not found so you are using the wrong path. I can't tell you the right one unless you explain where your `index.php` or `index.html` file is, where your `js` is and where your `php` is. If you get a blank page then you might actually have a blank file. Is the `jquery.js` file really where you think it is? Is it empty?

Comment: No, the JS file is not empty. It is located in the same folder as the index.php file :  http://localhost/folder_name/

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza OK, does it work if you create a minimal `.html` file (not `php`) and point it to `jquery`? If chrome gives you a blank page then there _is_ a file but it is empty.

Comment: I made a simple html file, including the javascript, and a simple test function of the jquery.  The html file gives a blank page. But when i make it a php file, I get the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: This was the code i put :   <div id="11">
 hello
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/analyst_scrape/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#11").click(fucntion(){

  alert("good bye");
 });

</script>

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza well, that just means you have a syntax error, you have `{` where you shouldn't. You really need to explain this more clearly. Please [edit] your question and give a minimal reproducible example. At the moment, we have to guess where your files are and what they look like. You need to set up the simplest possible case that gives you this error and provide us with everything necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: I gave you the example in the line above. The bracket is properly closed.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza my comment was written before you posted yours. Please [edit] your question to add new info instead of placing it in comments, it is very hard to read. Also, if you are giving URLs, you will need to use `http://localhost/foo/jquery.js`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12055/discussion-between-terdon-and-lawrence-desouza)